# How to establish a relationship between two tables?

Tags: core-data

I'm new to core data.

I have a data model, in which there are two tables and a 1-N relationship between them.

The application downloads all data from a service and saves the data in each table.

In addition, the tables are related and therefore want to do this:

a) Obtain all elements of the table2, which satisfies certain conditions.

b) For each element in table2, the identifier look table1 / save the table1´s id.

c) I get the item in Table 1 which meets the requirements ID.

d) I relate to Table 2 with 1.

I'm not capable for doing this. :(

I do not know if this method for make a relation between tables in this way is good or no.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of difficult to answer. If you think about Core Data as an SQL table you'll just get yourself into difficulty.

Core data isn't about joining and searching tables, it's about an object graph. An object has relationships to another object which has an inverse relationship to the other object. Essentially, what you should be looking to do is:

1. This is a fetch request of the entity which you are storing in table 2 subject to a predicate which defines your conditions.
2. You don't actually deal with ids directly in Core Data. You hardly ever deal with the keys directly.
3. Step 1 returned a collection of objects, and you can run a further predicate on this to filter it.
4. That is what the inverse relationship is for.

I know this doesn't answer your *actual question*. I'm trying to get you to think of your Core Data store as a collection of objects related to each other rather than as a bunch of linked tables.